# Cannot restore a new non-partitioned SSD using Clonezilla Preseed option

Tags: ssd, restore, clonezilla

- I can use the default manual step-by-step approach to restore the
  backup to a new non-partitioned SSD without any problems.
- I can restore using my automated unattended Clonezilla script to
  restore the backup to any partitioned SSD.
- I **cannot restore** using my automated unattended Clonezilla script to a
  new **non-partitioned SSD** as this gives out the following issue

> Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label

[image: error message]

This is my preSeed script (beware that I did format to ease readability):

```
menuentry "Flysoft RESTORE" {
  search --set -f /live/vmlinuz
  $linux_cmd /live/vmlinuz boot=live union=overlay username=user config components quiet noswap edd=on nomodeset enforcing=0 noprompt
ocs_prerun="mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt"
ocs_prerun1="mount --bind /mnt/images /home/partimag/"
ocs_live_run="ocs-sr -g auto -e1 auto -e2 -r -j2 -k -scr -batch -p reboot restoredisk ask_user sda"
keyboard-layouts="de"
ocs_live_batch="yes" locales=de_DE.UTF-8 vga=788 ip= nosplash net.ifnames=0 splash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1
  $initrd_cmd /live/initrd.img
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of Gparted that list your disks?

Comment: @Ramhound Since this a new disk and has no partitions, I need to boot using Ubuntu live and start GParted there. Is this approach correct?

Comment: Are you sure it has no partitions?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I am very sure. It is a new disk fresh out of the factory. You can see in above screenshot, that only sda exists; this tells that there are no partitions in the sda drive.